# Parse server error: Uncaught internal server error. {“stack”:“Error”}

Tags: parse-platform

I have user import query:

```
const userObj = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var addingList = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < downloadedCustomers.length; i++) {
  var user = new userObj();
  user.set("username", downloadedCustomers[i].cardcode);
  user.set("password", downloadedCustomers[i].password);
  user.set('name', downloadedCustomers[i].cardname);
  addingList.push(user)
  user.save( { useMasterKey: true }).then((success)=>{
    console.log(success)
  }).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

when i use this code on array, sometimes gives
`error: Uncaught internal server error. {“stack”:“Error”}` on some keys, but sometimes successfully saves all keys.

if i use :

```
Parse.Object.saveAll(addingList, { useMasterKey: true })
```

somekeys got saved, still some not saved.

How can i import all keys successful everytime?

PS: same situation on `user.signUp()`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it dividing object requests into 10 pieces of chunks.
Seems parse user object saving needs time process and resolve.

```
for (h = 0, k = addingList.length; h < k; h += chunk2) {
        temparray = addingList.slice(h, h + chunk2);
        await Parse.Object.saveAll(temparray,{useMasterKey:true}).then((success) => {
          console.log(h + chunk2 + ’ customers were added from total ’ + k);
          return h + chunk2 + ’ customers were added from total ’ + k
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log('Some customers were failed to import in chunk : ’ + h + ‘. Error:’ + error);
          console.log(error)
          return 'Some customers were failed to import in chunk : ’ + h + ‘. Error:’ + error
        });
      }
```

Chunk size should be below 20, because it's Default object array limit in saveAll() function.